# Relationship ignores soft delete after upgrade to 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my model I have the following relationship:

```
public function packages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Package');
}
```

After upgrading to 4.2, it is returning all soft deleted records, previously in 4.1 it was working fine. If I add `->whereNull('deleted_at')` to the relationship, it behaves as before.

The `Package` model is using traits for the soft deletes, as instructed at the upgrade procedure in the docs

Comment: are you using a BaseModel ?

Comment: Yes, no `SoftDeletingTrait` there. It will throw an error if I do.

Comment: and do you declare the trait in the sub model ?

Comment: I've run into a similar issue, though I am not inheriting so I have the use `SoftDeletingTrait` in the appropriate models and the relationship is a `belongToMany`. Using the `->whereNull('deleted_at') seems to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Soft deletes changed with the 4.2 update. I don't like the changes, but here's a link to the information that explains why your soft deletes aren't working:

http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade#upgrade-4.2

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 4.2 the Traits need to be in this shape:

If using a BaseModel:

```
class BaseModel extends Eloquent{
   protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];    
}

class SubModel extends BaseModel{
   use SoftDeletingTrait;
}
```

Apparently in laravel 4.2 using the traits, you can no longer declare a BaseModel as soft deletable and all submodels inherit this structure, you have to state `use SoftDeletingTrait;` in every submodel you have.

Comment: The relationship still returning soft deleted records. It works ok if I add `->whereNull('deleted_at')` to the relationship.